# Firstname and lastname input fields do not populate into the email body

Tags: html, windows-8

So I'm trying to adventure into the mystical world of windows 8 programming. I noticed I can code an app in HTML5 (COOL!) but I've ran into a bit of a bug in what I've written. There is no purpose to this app (at this time), just a simple form app to collect string value from text boxes, and vomit that into an email draft to prepare for sending.

This is my code:

```
<form action="MAILTO:email@mail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Your First Name"/><br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Your Last Name"/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

And when I click submit, it does open the Windows 8 mail app, with the proper sender field populated! However the firstname and lastname strings do not populate into the email body.

Any thoughts? This is all in my default.html file with Visual Studio. Here's a snippet of what I have

[image: snippet of Visual Studio]

Comment: It's Working Perfectly With Chrome. But You may be Using Internet Explorer? ie Does not support HTML5

Comment: Good point actually. Well it's actually opening all within Windows 8 itself, but I mostly use Mozilla Firefox. Do you think it could be trying to see HTML5 resources from IE? ("it" being Visual Studio)

Comment: Yes Visual Studio Use Internet Explorer. Just Copy Your Code in notepad and Save as HTML. it'll surely work with M FireFox as well!

Comment: That makes sense to me. I'll try it with there to test the code. Do you think (my goal overall is a functioning Win8 App, trying to get into a realm I'm new at) I can get away with getting it Via Java? I lost all my knowledge with C# :(

Comment: If you are doing Windows 8 development on a Windows 8 machine, you have Internet Explorer 10, which supports HTML5.  When running your Windows 8 app, some of the same underlying pieces are the same as those used by Internet Explorer (that is probably what Muhammad meant), but Visual Studio doesn't launch anything in a browser.  Macfan9000, cool for getting into Win8 development!  There are some helpful tips & tricks to help you build an app in 30 days (plus get free design consults & tech support) here: http://aka.ms/Jen30TLWin8

Answer (score 0):

Like Muhammad already said, HTML-apps are displayed via internet explorer (or et least it's engine). To avoid this you could use another webbrowser (like Gecko from Firefox) in your app and just put filling in the center of your XAML-app (which is close to HTML btw) and you could use C# which is IMO (looking at the syntax) not only close to Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing for Windows 8, then you are running the Windows 8 operating system and have Internet Explorer 10 by default, which supports HTML5.

I believe the issue may be with your code.  Try changing the "post" to "get", and specify the email body.  For example, this code works for me to insert the open textarea into the body of the email:

```
    <form action="MAILTO:email@mail.com" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
        <br/>
        <textarea name=Body></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
```